# Jquery add hash sign when try to add url params

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have problem when i try to add new params in existing url with `location.hash`. After adding new two params hash sign is automaticly added to url `#`

I have link: `http://work.example.rs/index.php/profile/photos` on click i open new modal window where i load full size image and add new param to url like `photo_id` and `photo_guid`

```
preview: function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#open-picture-modal', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var guid = $this.data('guid');
        var photo_id = $this.data('id');

        var url = baseurl + '/picture/preview/?pgid='+guid+'&pid='+photo_id;

        location.hash = "&pgid="+guid+"&pid="+photo_id; // <-- Here is line 

    });
},
```

After open modal url is changed like this:
`http://work.example.rs/index.php/profile/photos#&pgid=E10B6F66-9686-9E29-55BA-3C197004F608&pid=6`

In this url u can see `#` in url is added i dont know whay?

Html:

```
<?php $image_path = upload_userdata_url() .'/'. $photo->owner_id .'/'.'photos/'.$photo->photo_guid .'/'. $photo->photo_name;?>
<a href="<?= $image_path;?>" class="thumbnail" data-guid="<?= $photo->photo_guid; ?>" data-id="<?= $photo->photo_id; ?>" id="open-picture-modal" data-gallery>
<div class="uiMediaThumbImg" style="background-image: url(<?=$image_path;?>);"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: do you know what `hash` is? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: also your php code doesn't look like html as you said, if you want to post html - just post html from browser

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: You asking why `#` (hash) appears when you modify `.hash` param, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `hash` which append the `#` symbol to url. You can user [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) provided by `HTML5`

replace your line

```
location.hash = "&pgid="+guid+"&pid="+photo_id;
```

to

```
window.history.pushState('', '', "&pgid="+guid+"&pid="+photo_id);
```